# Is there a name for this distribution?

Tags: probability, parameter-estimation, maximum-likelihood

Is there a name for the distribution with PDF

$$f(x; \alpha, \beta) = \alpha\beta x^{\beta - 1}e^{-\alpha x^\beta}.$$

It looks very similar to the "Type-2 Gumbel Distribution" but I'm unsure. I have derived an MLE for the parameter $\alpha$ and I want to check if it is correct!

Comment: It is called the Weibull Distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is otherwise known as the Weibull distribution. It is typically used in reliability analysis. The probability density function in medical statistics takes this form you have described.

Comment: Cheers!${}{}{}{}$